# Projective dimension of the functions with compact support

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. And $C(X)$ the ring of all continous real-valued functions and $J(X)$ the ideal of such functions with compact support.
It is known that $X$ is paracompact iff $J(X)$ is projective, see https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1029000524 .

> Question 1: What is the projective dimension of $J(X)$ in general? (and can it be flat without being projective?I guess it is free iff $X$ is compact)
>
> Question 2: Is $C(X)$ studied from a homological algebra standpoint somewhere? For example, what is the global dimension or the injective dimension of the regular module? Or more generally, what is its finitistic dimension depending on $X$?

Comment: About Q2, note that a Gorenstein ring is supposed to be noetherian by definition.

Comment: @abx I asked now about the injective dimension of the regular module instead. (I thought one could define Gorenstein in general when both injective dimensions of the regular modules (on both sides) are finite).